# Frontend not working permission issue Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7, permissions

I get the following **error** report when attempting to go to the **frontend** of my **Magento 2 website**.

```
{"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(\/var\/lib\/php\/sessions\/sess_9am6mqijeelnptduc1lku9qhi3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

The **admin panel is working OK**.

This started when I created a duplicate of this site and went through the various set up commands on that new site.

I have temporarily updated the session folder to 777 to test - to no avail.

Can anyone please suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below command for permission.

```
 find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
 find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
 chown -R :www-data .
 chmod u+x bin/magento
 sudo chmod -R 777 pub var app/etc setup generated
```

Please let me know if it is worked or not.